# Defining the number $ e $

Tags: real-analysis, foundations

In [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNZgbj3UaRE) YouTube video it is said that $ e $ naturally arises as a number that allows us to take the derivatives of functions like $ a^x $. So $ e $ is defined as a number for which:
$$(e^x)'=e^x\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac {e^h-1}{h}=e^x$$

So essentially the limit should be $1 $ for this to happen. How would you prove that there *is* indeed such a real number, and find its value?

P.S.Please, don't say that there are other ways to define $ e $ - I know that. It's just this particular definition that seems natural and interesting to me.

Comment: Since you're using the "arithmetic" definition of $e^x$, to calculate that derivative you'll first need to prove it converges, covered in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678309/derivative-of-ax-from-first-principles).

Answer (score 2):

*If* you had a definition of $a^b$ (which most books base on having a definition of $\ln$ and $e$, so that $a^b := e^{b \ln a}$), you might say to yourself

1. $a^b$ depends continuously on $a$ and $b$ as long as $a$ and $b$ are positive.
2. When I compute $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2^h - 1}{h}$, I get a number less than 1.
3. When I compute $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{4^h - 1}{h}$, I get a number greater than 1.

Therefore by the intermediate value theorem, there should be a number $c$ with 
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{c^h - 1}{h} = 1.
$$

This depends, of course, on the well-definedness and continuity of the function

$$
F(b) =\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{b^h - 1}{h}
$$

which I cannot prove without either a very messy epsilon-delta argument, or relying on alternative definitions of $e$. But this is at least the gist of how you might go about things. I'd love to see your definition of $a^b$ for irrational $a$ and $b$, though, so that I could turn it into a real proof.

Comment: John's first displayed equation implies that the desired value of $c$ is $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} (1+h)^\frac{1}{h}$, which is indeed one way to define Euler's $e$.

Comment: My definition of $ a^b $ is as given in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732455/explicit-expression-for-xy-where-y-is-irrarional) question.

Comment: Yeah...with that definition, I need to know how you defined "log" (and how you prove the existence of $\log(x)$ for every positive $x$). I have a feeling that *I* would end up in circular-definition hell, so I won't pursue this. It's possible that someone *else* could do so profitably.